# How to rotate 3D text in python?

Tags: python-3.x, text

I tried rotation, but it does not work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D                         # 3d graph
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d                         # 3d graph
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5,6])
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.text(0, 0, 8.8, '$z$', 'z')    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: See some examples here of how to do it:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/text3d.html

Comment: I looked at this page, but I do not understand that. Could I ask for explanation?

Comment: If you can be more specific about what you don't understand, then I'll try to explain. Basically they use somewhat different functions to achieve the same goal. The code attached on the page shows you how to use those functions, and for more information you can always check the functions' documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this `ax.set_zlabel('z-label', rotation=90)`, I hope this works.

### Edit

The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/text3d.html) outlines how generic text can be rotated in 3D. Given a 3D figure, one can add text via:

```
ax.text(x, y, z, label, direction)
```

The `direction` argument controls the rotation, and it is either:

1. A 3-tuple specifying `(x, y, z)` directions
2. `'x'`, `'y'`, or `'z'`, specifying that the text should run parallel to the specified axis.